# pandas merge on columns one with duplicates

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes, one has a key column which have duplicates. They other key doesn`t have duplicates. I'd like to merge these dataframes on that key, it's like many correspondence key if df1 to one key in df2.
For example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['K0', 'K1', 'K2', 'K2', 'K2', 'K3'],
                'A':   ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5']}, 
               columns=['key', 'A'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'B':   ['B0', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4'],
                'key': ['K0', 'K1', 'K2', 'K3', 'K4']}, 
               columns=['key', 'B'])
  key   A
0  K0  A0
1  K1  A1
2  K2  A2
3  K2  A3
4  K2  A4
5  K3  A5

  key   B
0  K0  B0
1  K1  B1
2  K2  B2
3  K3  B3
```

I'm trying to get the following output

```
  key   A  B
0  K0  A0  B0
1  K1  A1  B1
2  K2  A2  B2
3  K2  A3  B2
4  K2  A4  B2
5  K3  A5  B3
```

Two tables have much more columns than the example. how I can accomplish this? 
many thanks~

Comment: Do you think `df1['B'] = df1['key'].map(df2.set_index('key')['B'])` ?

Comment: Isn't that a LEFT JOIN? Using `how='left` should work, I think. So `df1.merge(df2, how='left')`